# How not to print dots (.) instead of space and hyphens in an xslx file using the write.xlsx function?

Tags: r, excel, xlsx

Good night,

Earlier today I tried to print into a .xlsx (and also .xls) file a table which had names containing hyphens and dots, such as in the dummy example and the image below . However, only dots were printed in the place of the hyphens.

```
foo = cbind(c(2,4),c(4,6))
colnames(foo) = c("UP-DOWN.E","DOWN-EAST")
row.names(foo) = c("yesterday","now")
foo
```

[image: Table with names containing hyphens and dots]

Can anybody explain why that happens and how to fix it or at least avoid it happening again?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a feeling that this has something to do with the `check.names` option for `data.frame`. But without a minimum working example, can't help much. Not even sure what package you're using...

Comment: I tried using the xlsx package to print the dataframe to a file and the effect was what I explained earlier. It is quite odd,since in the R console the table is ok, with all the hyphens in the proper places...

And the small example I tried to provide was to show what kind of rownames I had before printing it. Still, I'm confused since it is the first time it has happened to me.

Comment: Could you try adding `check.names=FALSE` to your `write.xlsx(..., check.names=FALSE)`. I can't install it because I don't have java installed on this machine.

Comment: Brandon, if I do that, I only get an error message: 

 _Error in write.xlsx(planilhaFinalG2, "planilhaTeste.xlsx", check.names = F) :   unused argument (check.names = F)_

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more help. You'll have to look at the code and see where `data.frame` or `as.data.frame` is called and perhaps try overwriting the function it with the adjustment `...(...,check.names = FALSE)`.

Comment: @Bradon Bertelsen, curiously, adding as.data.frame in the line fixed the hyphen problem, as the code below. I still don't know why. Thanks a lot for the suggestion! Now all that is left is my curiosity why that happened... 

`write.xlsx(as.data.frame(planilhaFinalG2),"planilhaTeste.xlsx`

Comment: Write it as an answer and accept! Good work!